# Are any Gmail addons published by Google?

Tags: gmail

There are many Gmail addons. Are any of them published and maintained by Google?

My emails are private so I will only run software against my emails if that software is written by Google or myself.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/

Comment: For now there's only one Gmail add-on developed by Google, it's "Hired by Google", see https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/search/by%20google?hl=en&pann=gaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there are only one Gmail add-on published by Google: [Hire by Google](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/hire_by_google/61638575980).

It's worthy to say that at this time publishing Gmail add-ons submits a review request to Google. Ref. https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish

Comment: Google has a poor reputation for reviewing third-party apps/extensions on its platforms.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter it by "By Google":
**https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en&_feature=google**

unfortunately, there are not many for Gmail, however, you can try these, which are made with Google colaboration (at some degree):
**https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail**

Comment: The first link shows Chrome extensions not Gmail add-ons

Comment: A lot of developers put "Google" in the product name to trick potential users. Google does not appear to be effectively policing their trademarks here.